# User Sessions | Month's Since Last Active Using SQL

Tags: postgresql

| UserID | CalMonth | ActiveFlag | Months_since_last_active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2021 | 1 | 0 |
| A | 2/1/2021 |  | 1 |
| A | 3/1/2021 |  | 2 |
| A | 4/1/2021 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1/1/2021 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 2/1/2021 |  | 1 |
| B | 3/1/2021 | 1 | 0 |

Problem --> The first 3 colums are given. Generate the last one 'Months_since_last_active' by adding 1 until the use is active again

My Solution as below:

```
With active_sessions as (
Select 
  User_Id 
, CalMonth
, active flag as current_flag  
, LAG (ActiveFlag,1) over (partition by User_Id order by CalMonth) as previous_flag
) 

Select User_Id, CalMonth, current_flag, sum(case when current_flag =1 then 0 
                                                 when current_flag IS NULL then Months_since_last_active + 1 
                                            END
                                           ) as Months_since_last_active 
from active_sessions
order by 1,2
```

I was asked the above question in an interview and told that my proposed solution would not work because:

1. When it comes to 3/1/2021 and beyond, the previous values of 'Months_since_last_active' *are not in the table yet* -- they are only in the code
2. If I wanted to use LAG function, then it'd take innumerable LAG functions to achieve what I was trying to achieve

I will appreciate if someone can comment on my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution has 3 major problems, 2 of them may be related to copy/past errors. The `active_sessions` CTE is missing the `from clause`, so there is no data source. Then the main portion uses the aggregate function `SUM`, however, the query has no `group by` which is required for the aggregate function. These are easily corrected. The other issue concerns the `LAG` function and your use of it.  

First off in the CTE you alias the result as `previous_flag`, then in the main query you reference `Months_since_last_active` which does not exist yet. I think this is the source of the interviewer's first point.
The interviewer's second point also stems form the `LAG` function. As written it always looks back exactly 1 row, but from the current row yet it needs to look back 2 rows for (userid, calmonth) = ('A', 2021-03-01), and 3 rows for (A, 2021-04-01), etc. Basically you need to look back to to the last row with `active_flag = 1`. This leads directly to the *it'd take innumerable LAG functions* as you do not know how far beck you need to look. Suppose you had 30-40 or more *inactive rows* between *active rows*. You need a `LAG(activeflag,n) ...` for each possibility.  

A solution. I dislike the problem statement it should not contain *by adding 1 until the use is active* again (is it yours or theirs). Either way this is an  [XY](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/xy-problem-behind-every-what-why-brenda-lai). If theirs they should be telling you what to solve, i.e. *find number of months since last active*. If yours you have created the problem for yourself. The problem statement should **not** say anything about how to solve the it. I will ignore that portion of the problem (And in a real interview I would/have ignored it, but be prepared to explain why).  

What you have a a version of a `Gaps And Islands` (google it, you will find more that to think about). In this version lets consider each row with `activeflag = 'Y'` an as island, and anything else as a gap. Nor what you are looking for is the length of the gaps between islands. In the following the `island_num` CTE does 2 things. It assigns a sequence number to each row for a (userid, calmonth) and generates a boolean for each island. The `gap_points' then joins the results with itself, selecting the assigned for the max island whose calmonth is less than the current rows calmonth. In the main part the Months_since_last_active is assigned 0 if the current row is an island, and the difference between the generated row numbers if it is a gap. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d22ddc1d5a5eee6fd945100930b6a118))

```
with island_num (userid, cal_month, active_flag, is_island, row_num) as
     ( select am.* 
            , case when am.activeflag = 1 then true else false end is_island
            , row_number() over (partition by am.userid order by am.calmonth) rn
         from active_month am  
     ) -- select * from island_num 
   , gap_points(userid, cal_month, active_flag, is_island, row_num, island_row) as
     (  select * 
           from island_num i1
           join lateral 
                        (select max(row_num)  
                           from island_num i2
                          where i1.userid = i2.userid
                            and i2.cal_month < i1.cal_month
                            and i2.is_island
                        ) s0
                    on true
               
       ) --select * from gap_points; 
select userid       "User Id"
     , cal_month    "Cal Month" 
     , active_flag  "Active Flag"
     , case  when is_island then 0 
                            else row_num - island_row
       end "Months_since_last_active" 
  from gap_points;
```